# Calling elocation geocode API returns empty in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, geocode

I have this odd problem when calling eLocations geocoding API via Spark where i will always get an empty body even on addresses I know will return a coordinate. I am developing a geocoding app using Spark (2.3.3) and scala. I am also using scalaj to call the REST API. So the line of code which calls the API is as such:

```
def getGeoCoderLocation(sc: SparkSession, req: String, url: String, proxy_host: String, proxy_port: String, response_format: String): scala.collection.Map[String, (String, String)] = {
    import sc.implicits._

    val httpresponse = Http(url).proxy(proxy_host, proxy_port.toInt).postForm.params(("xml_request", req), ("format", response_format)).asString

    println(httpresponse.body)
    println(httpresponse.contentType.getOrElse(""))
    println(httpresponse.headers)
    println(httpresponse)
    if(!httpresponse.contentType.getOrElse("").contains("text/html")) {
      val body = httpresponse.body
      val httpresponse_body = parseJSON(Option(body).getOrElse("[{\"x\":, \"y\":}]"))

      val location = for (it <- 0 until httpresponse_body.length) yield {
        (Option(httpresponse_body(it)(0).x).getOrElse("").toString, Option(httpresponse_body(it)(0).y).getOrElse("").toString, it)
      }

      val locDF = location.toDF(Seq("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE", "row"): _*)//.withColumn("row", monotonically_increasing_id())
      locDF.show(20, false)
      locDF.rdd.map { r => (Option(r.get(2)).getOrElse("").toString, (Option(r.get(0)).getOrElse("").toString, Option(r.getString(1)).getOrElse("").toString)) }.collectAsMap()
    }
    else {
      val locDF = Seq(("","","-")).toDF(Seq("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE", "row"): _*)//.withColumn("row", monotonically_increasing_id())
      locDF.show(20, false)
      locDF.rdd.map { r => (Option(r.get(2)).getOrElse("").toString, (Option(r.get(0)).getOrElse("").toString, Option(r.getString(1)).getOrElse("").toString)) }.collectAsMap()
    }
  }
```

Where

- url = http://elocation.oracle.com/elocation/lbs
- proxy_host = (ip of proxy)
- proxy_port = (port number)
- req = `"<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n<geocode_request vendor=\"elocation\">\n\t(address_list)\n\t\t|<list of requests>|\n\t</address_list>\n</geocode_request>"`
- response_format = JSON

So when I print the body it will always be [{}] (i.e. empty JSON Array) when I run my app in Spark. When I run the same request without a spark-submit i will get a proper Array of JSON objects (e.g. java -jar test.jar).

Is there a setting in Spark which blocks the app from receiving REST responses? We are using Cloudera 5.16.x

I have also tried setting the proxy information using `--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dhttp.proxyHost=(ip) -Dhttp.proxyPort=(port) -Dhttps.proxyHost=(ip) -Dhttps.proxyPort=(port)"` but I will get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosAuthException: Login failure for user: (principal) from keytab (keytab) javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Cannot locate KDC
```

Please help as I don't know where to look to solve this as i have never encounter this before.

Comment: _LoginException: Cannot locate KDC_ sounds like your Kerberos configuration (`krb5.conf` file) is either bad or can't be located at runtime

Comment: only happens when i put in the proxy stuff in spark.executor.extraJavaOptions. When i remove those options i don't get that error.

Comment: can you post full code how are you invoking rest api from spark code ??

Comment: edited. i put the whole function that calls the rest api.

Comment: i forgot to mention that this code works when run in another environment. Just that in my client's env it is having this funny behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok found the cause. the payload was actually empty which is why elocation keep returning blank.

Lesson of the day, check your payload.